# Do wave maps preserve geometric constraints $|\phi|=1$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\phi : \mathbb{R}^{1+d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m+1}$ be a classical solution to the nonlinear wave equation
$$ \partial^2_{tt} \phi - \Delta \phi = ( - |\partial_t \phi|^2 + |\nabla \phi|^2 ) \phi \, . $$

Show that if the initial data $(\phi(0,x), \partial_t \phi (0,x) )$ obeys the conditions
$$ \phi(0,x) \cdot \phi(0,x) = 1\, ; \phi(0,x) \cdot \partial_t \phi(0,x) = 0\, , $$
then we have
$$ \phi(t,x) \cdot \phi(t,x) = 1\, ; \phi(t,x) \cdot \partial_t \phi(t,x) = 0\, , $$
for all times $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Let's define $\mu = |\phi|^2$.  A direct computation reveals that
$$
 \partial_t^2 \mu - \Delta \mu    
= 2(1-\mu) ( |\partial_t u|^2 -  |\nabla u|^2),
$$
and so $\mu$ solves this wave equation with data $\mu(0) = 1$ and $\partial_t \mu(0) = 2\phi(0)\cdot \partial_t \phi(0)=0$.

The wave-type problem 
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t^2 \xi -\Delta \xi + \rho \xi = f \\
\xi(0) = g, \partial_t \xi(0) = h
\end{cases}
$$
admits unique classical solutions as long as $\rho, f,g,h$ are "nice enough."  For the above $\mu$ problem, since we assume $u$ is a classical solution, the corresponding $\rho, f, g, h$ are "nice enough," and so the problem for $\mu$ admits unique solutions.

However, we can easily check by hand that $\theta(x,t) =1$ identically solves the same PDE as $\mu$ and satisfies the same initial conditions.  By uniqueness we then have that $\mu = \theta$ identically, i.e. 
$$
|\phi(x,t)|^2 = \mu(x,t) = \theta(x,t) =1 \text{ for all }x,t.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it ! By the way, I have anther question. Does the following equation preserve 0 solution ?
\begin{align}
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
   \partial_t^2 \xi - \lambda_1 \partial_t \xi - \Delta \xi = \gamma \xi \\
  \xi(0) = 0, \partial_t \xi (0) = 0 , \\
 \end{array} \right.
\end{align}
where $\lambda_1$ is constant and $\gamma$ is "nice enough".